# Java program doesn't add objects to ArrayList

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist

I'm trying to add different objects to an `ArrayList` and it's not working. I'm not sure if it's because I'm adding objects incorrectly or if there's something else wrong.

Here's my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class QuizBowl implements Quiz {  
   private Player player;     // player object
   private String file;       // name of file
   private int qNum;          // number of questions player wants to answer
   private int qNumFile;      // number of questions in file
   private ArrayList<Question> questionsArr; // holds Question objects
   private boolean questionsAsked[]; // array of questions that were already asked



   // Constructor
   public QuizBowl(String fName, String lName, String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
      player = new Player(fName, lName);
      Scanner gameFile = new Scanner(new File(file));
      qNum = numOfQuestionsToPlay();
      qNumFile = maxNumQFile(gameFile);
      questionsArr = new ArrayList<Question>();
      readFile();
      System.out.println(questionsArr);
      questionsAsked = new boolean[qNumFile];     
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(questionsAsked));
   }

   // asks user how many questions to ask
   public int numOfQuestionsToPlay() {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 

      // CHECKS FOR VALID USER INPUT
      boolean check = false;
      do {
           try {
               System.out.print("How many questions would you like (out of 3)? ");
               int answer = console.nextInt();
               if(answer > 3) {
                  System.out.println("Sorry, that is too many.");
                  check = false;
               }               
               else {
                  check = true;        
               }              
           }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
               System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
               console.nextLine(); 
               check = false;  
            }
       }
       while(check == false);
       return qNum; 
   }

   // figures out how many questions are in the file 
   public int maxNumQFile(Scanner gameFile) {
      int num = gameFile.nextInt();
      return num;   
   }

   // LOOP FOR READING QUESTIONS    
   public void readFile() {
       for(int i = 0; i < qNum; i++) {
           readQuestion();
       }
   }

    // READS QUESTION AFTER QUESTION AND ADDS TO THE ARRAYLIST OF QUESTIONS OBJECTS
    public void readQuestion() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        console.nextLine();
        String[] line;
        String question, questionType;
        int points;

        line = console.nextLine().split(" "); 

        questionType = line[0];  
        points = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);  
        question = console.nextLine();

        if(questionType.equals("MC")) {      // checks if question type is MC
            questionsArr.add(readMC(questionType, question, points, console));               // adds MC question to array
        }
        else if(questionType.equals("SA")) { // checks if question type is SA                    
            questionsArr.add(readSA(questionType, question, points, console));               // adds SA question to array           
        }
        else {                                        // checks if question type is TF
            questionsArr.add(readTF(questionType, question, points, console));               // adds TF question to array
        }
    }

    // READS ONE TF QUESTION
    public static QuestionTF readTF(String questionType, String question, int points, Scanner console) {                      // returns new QuestionTF object
        String ans = console.nextLine();
        return new QuestionTF(question, questionType, points, ans);
    }

    // READS ONE SA QUESTION
    public static QuestionSA readSA(String questionType, String question, int points, Scanner console) {
        String ans = console.nextLine();
        return new QuestionSA(question, questionType, points, ans);                        // returns new QuestionSA object
    }

    // READS ONE MC QUESTION
    public static QuestionMC readMC(String questionType, String question, int points, Scanner console) {
        int numChoices;
        String[] choices;
        String ans;
        numChoices = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
        choices = new String[numChoices];
        ans = console.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < numChoices ; i++) {
            choices[i] = console.nextLine();
        }

        return new QuestionMC(question, questionType, points, choices, ans);  // returns new QuestionMC object
    }

    // STARTS QUIZ
    public void quiz() {
        int qCount = 0;
        int ranQ;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userAns;

        Random r = new Random();

        // RUNS QUIZ 
        while (qCount < qNum) {
            ranQ = r.nextInt(qNumFile);

            // CHECKS IF QUESTION HAS ALREADY BEEN ASKED
            if (!checkDup(ranQ, questionsAsked)) {
                questionsAsked[ranQ] = true;
                Question question = questionsArr.get(ranQ); // GETS RANDOM QUESTION FROM ARRAY
                question.printQuestion();    // prints question and points
                userAns = userInput.next();  // retrieves answer from user
                // CHECKS USER'S ANSWER
                if(userAns.equals("SKIP")) {
                    System.out.println("You have chosen to skip this question.");
                }
                else {
                    checkAnswer(userAns, question, player);
               }

               qCount++;
               System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    // CHECKS IF QUESTION HAS ALREADY BEEN ASKED
    public boolean checkDup(int ranQ, boolean questionsAsked[]){
        return questionsAsked[ranQ];
    }


    // CHECKS ANSWER AND ADDS POINTS
    public void checkAnswer(String userAnswer, Question question, Player player) {
        if(question.checkAnswer(userAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("Correct you get " + question.getPoints());
            player.setScore(question.getPoints());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect, the answer was " + question.getAnswer() + "." + 
            " you lose " + question.getPoints() + ".");
            player.setScore(question.getPoints() * -1);
        }
    }

   // Executes program
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {     
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter your first name: ");
      String first = console.next();
      System.out.print("Please enter your last name: ");
      String last = console.next();     
      System.out.print("Please enter the game file name: ");
      String file = console.next();

      QuizBowlRedo newGame = new QuizBowlRedo(first, last, file);    // creates new game of QuizBowl
      newGame.quiz();                                                // starts game
   } 
}
```

Here is a constructor for one of my object classes. QuestionMC, QuestionSA, and QuestionTF extend the Question class:

```
public QuestionSA(String question, String questionType, int points, String answer) {
      super(question, questionType, points);
      this.answer = answer;
   }
```

And here is the text file that I'm reading from:

```
3 
TF 5
There exist birds that can not fly. (true/false) 
true 
MC 10 
Who was the president of the USA in 1991? 
6 
Richard Nixon 
Gerald Ford 
Jimmy Carter 
Ronald Reagan 
George Bush Sr. 
Bill Clinton 
E 
SA 20 
What city hosted the 2004 Summer Olympics? 
Athens
```

The part I'm talking about starts at the `readQuestion()` method. And I'm trying to add objects to the `ArrayList` in the areas with the comments saying "READS ONE .... QUESTION". So far, it's coming out with an empty `ArrayList`.

Comment: What error are you getting? Always include the error you are getting.

Comment: There's no actual error that pops up; the program compiles. My only issue is adding objects to the ArrayList.

Comment: What is the relationship among Question, QuestionTF, QuestionSA, QuestionMC?

Answer (score 0):

1. `readFile()` is looping until qnum and calling `readQuestion()`. However, it does not pass the "current" question number to `readQuestion()`.  so `readQuestion()` always starts from the first?
2. `readQuestion()` is openning the input file (and thus, probably read the first question over and over again). it is probably the task of `readFile()`
3. The first line of the method reads from stdin. You probably meant to read from gameFile scanner?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your first two comments. For the first one, are you saying I should do something like `readQuestion(i)`? I'm not sure what it's supposed to if you pass the "current" question number. Also, I don't know what you mean when you say the `readQuestion()` is opening the input file.

Comment: ask yourself this question - how is readQuestion going to "know" which question is it reading? when it is called the second time (presumably to read the 2nd question) how is it supposed to know that this is the 2nd time it is called?

Comment: that must be the error in my logic, I thought that `Scanner gameFile` would hold the pointer wherever it's at. Thus, the pointer would continuously move down the file through the loop.

Comment: you are right. it does hold a pointer. it should work once you will use the correct scanner

Comment: in my code, I have two Scanners set up. To read the rest of my file, I should be using the `Scanner gameFile` one instead of `Scanner console`, correct? I'm thinking this is what you mean when you said use the correct Scanner.